# Read and write to a file from a QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel, qmodelindex

How can I read and write to a text file date enter to a QTableView?

This is what I have but I would like to save the data when it is added to the table and of course be able to read it back when the application is reopened. Is there any tutorial I can refer to?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model = new QStandardItemModel();
    model->setRowCount(0);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QStandardItem *userName = new QStandardItem(ui->lineEdit_Name->text());
    QStandardItem *userNumber = new QStandardItem(ui->lineEdit_Number->text());

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row <<userName << userNumber;

    model->appendRow(row);
}
```

Thanks a lot

**EDIT --------------------------------**

This is what worked for me:

Add Function:

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButto_Add_clicked() {
     QStandardItem *userInput = new QStandardItem(ui->lineEdit->text());
     QStandardItem *userInput2= new QStandardItem(ui->lineEdit_2->text());

     QList<QStandardItem*> row;
     row <<userInput << userInput2;

     model->appendRow(row); 
}
```

Save Function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Save_clicked()
{
    QFile file("C:/Users/UserName/Practicing/Resources_Files/someFile.bin");

     if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
     {
         QDataStream stream(&file);
         qint32 n = model->rowCount();
         qint32 m = model->columnCount();
         stream << n << m;

         for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
         {
          for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
              model->item(i,j)->write(stream);
            }
          }
        file.close();
      }
}
```

Load Function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Load_clicked()
{

    QFile file("C:/Users/UserName/Practicing/Resources_Files/someFile.bin");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QDataStream stream(&file);
        qint32 n, m;
        stream >> n >> m;
        model->setRowCount(n);
        model->setColumnCount(m);

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
               for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                   QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
                   item->read(stream);
                   model->setItem(i, j, item);
               }
           }

     file.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
QFile file("somefile.bin");

if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    stream << *(model->invisibleRootItem());
    file.close();
}
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html#invisibleRootItem

---

### Edit:

Here is correction (I've checked that it works).

```
void MainWindow::save()
{
    QFile file("somefile.bin");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QDataStream stream(&file);
        qint32 n(model->rowCount()), m(model->columnCount());
        stream << n << m;

        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                model->item(i,j)->write(stream);
        file.close();
    }
}

void MainWindow::load()
{
    QFile file("somefile.bin");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QDataStream stream(&file);
        qint32 n, m;
        stream >> n >> m;

        model->setRowCount(n);
        model->setColumnCount(m);
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                model->item(i,j)->read(stream);
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

If I use the snippet you suggested the only thing that gets saved is this symbol " ˇ  " (without the quotes), any idea what am I doing wrong? - FYI - If I change  stream << *(model->invisibleRootItem()); to stream << "Hello World"; it does save the string.

    QFile file("/Users/UserName/SourceFolder/someFile.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QDataStream stream(&file);
        stream << stream << "Hello World";;
        file.close();
    }

Comment: Ok I assumed that this writes all data recursively, but it doesn't. Docs says "Writes the item to stream out. Only the data and flags of the item are written, not the child items." http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditem.html#write. This can be easily fixed.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for your help! I will play around with this code to have better understanding on how this works.

Comment: One more question, can you or someone explain how the qint32 works, how did you know it get two arguments (n , m)? What its actually doing? Sorry but I would like to understand the code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Read QDataStream documentation. This is class to handle binary data format, so when you write `int`s you have to define size of it so same file could be read/write on other kinds of machines (for example when code is compiled for x64 simple `int` is 64 bits). There are also other types of issues, just read docs.

Comment: I actually read the docs but I still don't know exactly what qint32 is doing in the way we are using it,-  qint32 n(model->rowCount()), m(model->columnCount()); -  Are the n() and m() anonymous functions? If yes, where in the documentation shows that qint32 takes two anonymous functions? Sorry if I don't see the obvious. Thanks

Comment: noooo, qint32 is just a typedef under macro control. You have just warranty that it will be 32 bits on any system/compiler and so on (int can have different size). `qint32 n(model->rowCount())` is equivalent of `qint32 n = model->rowCount()`, so nothing fancy just standard C++ initialization..

Comment: Cool, I knew it was something simple, sorry but I didn't know variables could be initialized like that, make sense now, I now feel a lot better.  One more thing (I know I know I'm a pain), for some reason if I open the program and try to load the data from the file the program crashes, but if I open the program and start adding items to the table, save them to the file, than I can press the load button and the program doesn't crash anymore, but if I delete a row and hit the load button again it crashes. Any idea? thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think I can figure this out by my own, I think I need to draw the table before loading the file.

Comment: I thought I could figure this out but no luck. 
Here is my issue, I have three buttons, Add, Save and Load.
For some reason if I open the program and try to load the data from the file the program crashes, but if I open the program and start adding empty rows (enough for the data in the file) to the table and then press the load button it works fine, it loads the data. Any idea what could be wrong? - FYI, if I delete the for loops from the load function and press the load button I can see that it actually draws the rows needed to load the data, thats got to be something wrong in the for loops.

Comment: I added the solution to my problem in my original question, I modified the for loop from the load function a little bit. Thank you all a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse your model row by row, column by column and fill a file with a format like CSV (a row by line and columns separated by coma or tabs).

But, I don't think that is a good idea to modify the file when an item has changed. You should write the file when your application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

`model->item(i,j)->write(stream);` will lead to **segmentation fault** if `item(i,j)` is empty. Assign some dummy value like whitespace in empty cells.

Comment: This helped me solve an issue I was having, and you are correct. Do you know how I should go about writing whitespace to the blank items within `on_pushButton_Save_clicked`?