# Qt - Saving and Loading data from a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, save, load, qtablewidget

I'm trying to save my data of a QTableWidget to an external file. Firstly, I have no idea where to start since I haven't done this stuff before, so please give an example or something. Secondly, If im saving a QTableWidget's data it will have to be saved in table format, so what type of file do I save it in? As you can probably tell I don't really know what to do here. I also want to load data back into this table. All and any help is appreciated, thank you! if you can also explain what you have done, that would be amazing thank you!

EDIT:
Thanks guys for the help, firstly I changed the QTableWidget to a QTableView, secondly I read the other question linked by Marek R, and it was of great help, but now im getting sigsegv error. I don't know why. code below for the save function:

```
QStandardItem *rowitems = new QStandardItem();
QStandardItem *columnitems = new QStandardItem();
QList<StandardItem*> rowitem;
rowitem << rowitems;
QList<StandardItem*> columnitem;
columnitem << columnitems;
model->appendRow(rowitem);
model->appendColumn(columnitem);

void MainWindow::on_actionsave_Timetable_triggered()
{
if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
{
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    qint32 rows = model->rowCount();
    qint32 columns = model->columnCount();
    stream<<rows<<columns;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<rows;++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
             model->item(i,j,)->write(stream);
        }
     }
    file.close();
}
}
```

The top part of the code is in a constructor (the constructor also contains all the other stuff for setting up the QTableView's model). I don't know what to do from here.

EDIT 2:
Figured out my problem, you cannot save the file if you leave one of the spaces in the TableView blank, i.e. it must be filled with something like whitespace, a character etc. Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you provide us the kind of data you have in the table? 
Do you have any preferred table format? 
What will you do once the table is saved?
Do you need any kind of portability?

Comment: QString data, so words and characters will be in the table. I don't really have any preferred format. I need to have the table stored for loading every time I start the program up. I don't think I need any kind of probability.

Comment: I advise you should look in to the model of the QTableWidget. Have you looked in to the Qt Table Model Widget example?

Comment: No, may you please link me to it, many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and write to a file from a QTableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060146/read-and-write-to-a-file-from-a-qtableview)